# QGIS 3, Expression to address ranges in the symbology

Tags: qgis-3, fields-attributes, expression

I noticed many new entries in the list of expressions in the QGIS3-Version. 
Is there an expression that I can use to address the symbology of a Layer?
It would be of particular interest to get the upper and lower boundaries of the selected "graduated color" symbology.

I use QGIS 3.4.6.
[image]

Comment: Can you add some screenshots of the features you're talking about? I don't see anything about legends in the "symbology" section of layer properties.

Comment: Are you after the min and max values of the field used for symbology or are your symbology based on other value ?